# Posting XML to WCF

Tags: xml, wcf, wcf-binding

I am posting a custom XML to my endpoint but I am getting the following error:

The exception message is 'Unable to deserialize XML body with root name 'ABCXML' and root namespace '' (for operation 'SendLendingTreePayLoad' and contract ('IABCServices', 'SBA.ABCServices')) using DataContractSerializer. Ensure that the type corresponding to the XML is added to the known types collection of the service.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:

XML request object is similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ABCXML>
 <Version>5.3</Version>
 <ReferenceSource>7</ReferenceSource>
</ABCXML>
```

if i use this everything works fine:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
 some string here 
</string>
```

This is my Interface:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "SendXMLPayLoad")]
    long SendXMLPayLoad(string XML);
```

How can I fix this ?